# How to write title of chapter and algorithm in correct way?

Tags: titles, algorithms, algorithm2e

I am writing PhD Thesis on overleaf but the title of the chapter being vanished whenever I insert the package `\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}` for the algorithm and the algorithm appears in good formate. Whenever I am removing the package `\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}` the algorithm appears in bad formate and the title appears in good formate.

Anyone with this link can edit this project
https://www.overleaf.com/9127796831jszrmzbxmfyn
Anyone with this link can view this project
https://www.overleaf.com/read/zswrfmqdbpft

you can access the overleaf file by above link. Please go to `conclusion.tex` to see the change in chapter 3 and go to the `main.tex` file for package change.

Comment: One problem with the template is the use of `book.cls`. It's been modified and doesn't work properly when generating `\chapter`s.

Comment: I shared the formate only, did not share my actual version of the thesis, so please inform me which file need to modified or delete?

Comment: What you shared is a project that has a file called `book.cls`. Are you saying you don't have that as part of your version? It's difficult to help you without seeing exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: sorry, I was busy with some other work, I am sharing that link where is the same error are present, you go through the following link: https://www.overleaf.com/5571471828tjhwmgqmzwqc

Comment: the error: chapter heading is not in correct formate when involve the package \usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current problem with your setup is the redefinition of `\@chapter` inside the `book.cls` class. Typically `\@chapter` is defined to take *two* arguments - the first being optional and the second mandatory (taken from [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co)):

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```

Your class has been modified to make `\@chapter` take *three* arguments:

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2#3{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne %%%Changed by Rajarshi
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#2}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#1}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#3}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```

Rajarshi must have had something in mind here... :)

[`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) taps into `\@chapter` to insert content into the List of Algorithms (LoA), but it doesn't keep the *three*-argument definition of `\@chapter`. Here's the definition inside `algorithm2e.sty`:

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\algocf@original@chapter[#1]{#2}\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}%
```

This has to change to

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2#3{\algocf@original@chapter[#1]{#2}{#3}\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}%
```

so that the third argument is captured properly.

There are more problems, but this at least solves the issue with `\chapter`s.

Comment: thank you very much